# How to lock thread correctly with ReentrantLock or Mutex?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an acync method with callback:

```
myAsyncMethod(params) {
    handleResult(it)
}
```

I need to convert it to sync method (block and return result) like this:

```
val result = mySyncMethod(params)
handleResult(result)
```

I can't re-implement it by another way because this method provided by third-party library.

I am trying to use ReentrantLock:

```
fun mySyncMethod(params:Type) {
    Log.d("tag", "1")
    val result = null
    val mutex = ReentrantLock()
    myAsyncMethod(params) {
        Log.d("tag", "3")
        result = it
        mutex.unlock()
    }
    Log.d("tag", "2")
    mutex.lock()
    Log.d("tag", "4")
    return result
}

handleResult(mySyncMethod(params))
```

I wait that I should see 1, 2, 3, 4. But I get 1, 2, 4, 3 and null in handleResult. I am trying the same with mutex but with the same result. How to make it works?

P.S. Sure I can use synchronized, but in this case I have to use Object-variable additionally.

Comment: @Anatolii it used in non-UI threads. It should block thread.

Comment: It seems you forgot to invoke `mutex.lock()` before async method call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I expect that I should see 1, 2, 3, 4.

Then you misunderstood what `ReentrantLock` is actually for.

If `mySyncMethod` can be called from different threads, then after `mutex.lock()` is called, only one thread at a time can execute the code following `mutex.lock()` - the other threads executing this method have to wait. Once `mutex.unlock()` is called, one of the waiting threads will execute the code too and so on.

So, the thread owning the `mutex` forces the other threads to wait but its own flow isn't blocked. `myAsyncMethod` starts running after the outer method has completed already and hence `result` is still `null`.

> I need to convert it to sync method (block and return result) like this:

According to your requirements, you need to block the current thread until the async task is complete. To achieve this, you could use [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) or [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). For example, with `Semaphore`, your method could look as follows:

```
fun mySyncMethod(params:Type) {
    Log.d("tag", "1")
    val result = null
    val semaphore = Semaphore(0)
    myAsyncMethod(params) {
        Log.d("tag", "3")
        result = it
        semaphore.release()
    }
    Log.d("tag", "2")
    semaphore.acquireUninterruptibly()
    Log.d("tag", "4")
    return result
}
```

Comment: There is no method acquireUninterruptibly() available in Android. But a solution with CountDownLatch works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code first. I used a thread instead of your method to test myself.

```
fun main() {
    val mutex = ReentrantLock(true)
    val asyncCondition = mutex.newCondition()
    mutex.lock()
    try
    {
        print(1)


        thread {
            mutex.lock()
            try
            {
                print(2)
            }
            finally
            {
                asyncCondition.signalAll()
                mutex.unlock()
            }
        }

        asyncCondition.await()
        print(3)
    }
    finally
    {
        mutex.unlock()
    }
}
```

Java's `ReentrnatLock.lock` method will block a thread when it is already locked on the only same thread. Since you are trying to lock an async thread from another thread, your code is not working. To block or release another thread, you may use a `Condition` like my code.

The reason why I am using `try..finally`statement everywhere is that if an exception occurred after locking a thread, you are going to meet the infinity loop, so you must be careful about this case.

You may see these references.

- [Concurrency (ReentrantLock) in different threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586285/concurrency-reentrantlock-in-different-threads)
- [How do java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36435753/how-do-java-util-concurrent-locks-condition-work)